# Display dynamic header for each page when printing

Tags: javascript

We might have multiple pages when printing, but wanna show different header for each page. Found a solution to repeatedly show header on each page (https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a), but this only works when header text are the same, or else all the headers would be overlapped. So is there anyway to do this?

Comment: if all their style and design are different then write all header designs then hide all. in pages' js display each page header as a way

Comment: Do you have an example or demo for this? I didnt really get it all, sorry.